# access is denied while getting remote machine information in c#

Tags: c#

i m trying to get OS System from a remote machine connected in a lan .. 
i m using the following code .. 
i m getting an error "ACCESS IS DENIED"
can any one help me please ..  Thanx in advance

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\"+ ip +"\\root\\cimv2");
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery();
query.QueryString = "select  * from Win32_OperatingSystem";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
```

Comment: Your user account doesn't have access to run that query.

Answer (score 0):

See [WMI Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the following paragraph:

> Give the user Remote Launch and Remote Activation permissions in
>   dcomcnfg. Right-click My Computer-> Properties Under COM Security,
>   click "Edit Limits" for both sections. Give the user you want remote
>   access, remote launch, and remote activation. Then go to DCOM Config,
>   find "Windows Management Instrumentation", and give the user you want
>   Remote Launch and Remote Activation. For more information, see
>   Connecting Between Different Operating Systems.